# WIndows Server 2019 + SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Performance Issues (vs Win Server 2016)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019, windows-server-2019

Until now we were Running a MSSQL 2019 Enterprise Server on Windows Server 2016. The MSSQL-Server is used for Business Intelligence, so it's also executing SSIS-Packages, stored in the Integration Services Catalog, using a SQL Server Agent Job. On the Windows 2016 Server this job took about 4 minutes for a regular refresh.

After switching to the new Windows Server 2019 it takes about 12 minutes, or three times slower. I already checked all settings of SQL Server and Databases. They all match the old setup. Disk, CPU and RAM also match and benchmarks show no issues. Also the new Server uses new Storage which is much faster than the old one. So it all comes down to Network Performance which seems to be far worse in Windows Server 2019 than 2016.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue here? I googled around and couldn't find any real solution to this. It seems like it's known that Win 2019 has less Performance than 2016. But the threads talking about this (without a solution) are several years old. I can't believe that this hasn't been resolved in the last 3 years.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Additional Explanation:
The SSIS Packages load Data from different locations. Another MSSQL-Server running on a Win 2016 Server and several Postgres-DBs running on Debian. The Data is stored on the mentioned SQL Server on Win 2016 (old) / 2019 (new) Server. Sure there are Lookups in the Packages. But the Packages are exactly the same. Also are the Databases, Tables, SQL Server Configuration and so on. The only difference is the Operating System. I'm exoecting the issue being around the Network Interface/Functionality of the OS because CPU, RAM, SSD are all ruled out because they are also identical and Benchmarks show no Issues. Also I noticed huge differences on Copying a 1GB File to the Servers using Remote-Desktop. The Copy on 2016 Server takes about 1:40min and on the 2019 Server 3:30min. Will do more benchmarks.

Update: I made additional tests. I wanted to know where exactly the ssis-Packages take longer to execute. So I made this setup: I installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise on both Windows Servers, the 2016 and the 2019 one. Then I copied the SSIS-Project to both machines and configured them to use the MSSQL-Database of it's localhost. Then I first executed single packages and then a larger Master-Package. After this I compared the Execution Times. And there was no difference. All packages executed in Visual Studio directly on the Server took almost the same amount of time.
Then I created a simple SQL Agent Job on both machines to execute the larger Master Package and only that. In Visual Studio the execution took about 2:40 minutes on both Machines. When I executed the same packe with the SQL Agent Job I got the following durations:

Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2019: 2:01 minutes
Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2019: 3:43 minutes

So the 2016 Setup was faster using the SQL Agent (which is reasonable because less overhead than the VS Execution), but the 2019 Setup was about 30% slower. As the Visual Studio Execution is virtualy the same than the SQL Server Agent Execution there has to be an issue with the SQL Server Agent causing it o be much slower as the one of the SQL Server running on Windows 2019. I have no idea what this could be.

Comment: To restate: Srv2016 runs SSIS package that takes 3 minutes. Srv2019 runs same SSIS package that now takes 12 minutes. You believe the issue to be network related. Where does the package source its data and where does it land it? Are there lookups in this package and if so, where does that data come from?

Comment: @billinkc I expanded my Question with further explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the mystery. Our environment is a ProxMox Virtualization Environment. The Harddisks of the SQL Server were mounted as SCSI. After we switched to SATA it got a huge increase in Perfomance. I don't know why because SCSI should be faster. All the drivers were up to date and the SCSI Controller was in Write Back-Mode. But this is an issue of our IT where I'm not involved. The reason for the drop in perfomance was because the old Server used SATA und the new one SCSI, as I said.